# Run Windows 10 IoT app at startup?

Tags: windows-iot

I have a .NET universal application which I deployed to Raspberry Pi 2. It runs when I select "Debug" in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. But whenever Raspberry shuts down, I need to start the app again.

How can I make my app run at startup time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are the following ways:

1.) Set the app as default app via the Webbrowser

[image: Set default app via webbrowser]

2.) Via a [PowerShell connection (MS IoT Github)](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm). When connected, type

```
    iotstartup add headed HelloRaspi
```

where `HelloRaspi` is the name of the app and `headed` means that it has a user interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer following article to better understand the process of registering  startup app using PowerShell as well as WindowsIoT's WebManagement Portal:
https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-setting-startup-app-887ed0

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sure sir. I'll improve this answer as well as the future answers. I'll take care about this.